# Fastest way to build an XML request with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I am accessing a certain web service API which requires XML data in the request. For example, the API might be expecting:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<root>
    <a>1</a>
    <b>2</b>
</root>
```

What's the easiest way to build that XML request, possibly using jQuery? Is there any standard serializer that I can use to build a JS object and serialize it to XML? What's the idiomatic way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option I found (which I am currently using, pending no better option) is the [**json2xml** plugin for jQuery](http://michalkorecki.com/content/introducing-json-xml-jquery-plugin).

Example usage:

```
var xmlHead = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>';

var j = {
    a : '1',
    b : 'B',
    c : {
      m : 'm'
    }
};

var opts = {
  rootTagName : 'myRoot',
  nodes : ['a', 'b', 'c']
};

var xml = $.json2xml(j, opts);
var xmlData = xmlHead + xml;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could you [GSerializer](http://code.google.com/p/gserializer) API's to serialize and deserialize javascripts objects. Here is a sample code

```
var myObject = new MyObject(); // The object to serialize
var serializer = new GSerializer(); // The Serializer
var serializedXML = serializer.serialize(myObject, 'MyObject'); // Grab the serialized XML
var deserializedObject = serializer.deserialize(serializedXML); // Deserialize the object from the serialized XML string
```

Refer [this](http://www.onegeek.com.au/articles/programming/javascript-serialization.php) article for more details.

Comment: +1 Works like a charm for me. And no overhead in terms of jQuery / JSON needed.